# how to post variables to file like jquery ajax but with php

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I'm working on a project where I have to include a third party application in our system. This application transmitts parameters to a PHP file using jQuery ajax when calling the index.php. The exact function looks like this:

```
$.ajax( {
    type : "POST",
    cache : false,
    crossDomain : false,
    async : true,
    url : "/somwhere/somefile.php",
    data : "msg=37120&hello=true&USRID=1"
    )};
```

I'm am not very experienced with AJAX at all but as far as I can see in the end the parameters `"msg=37120&hello=true&USRID=1"` get postet on somefile.php. Now I want to  post the variables directly onto somefile.php using PHP instead of JS/AJAX.

After some researches I found the following solution to send post data directly to the `somefile.php`:

```
$url = "/somwhere/somefile.php";

$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "msg=37120&hello=true&USRID=1");

$response = curl_exec( $ch );
```

Unfortunately this is not working at all. No data arrives when I'm executing this code block. I've no idea what I'm doing wrong. Can someone tell me whats the mistake here?
Or is there even a better way how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Sorry -- I posted the get, below is the code to post.

This is the code that I use that works well:

```
$cookie="cookie.txt";
$useragent="Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30)";

$data=array(
  "field1" => 'data1',
  "field2" => 'data2',
  "SUBMIT" => 'true'
);

    $cr = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);       // Get returned value as string (dont put to screen)
    curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);      // Spoof the user-agent to be the browser that the user is on (and accessing the php $
    curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);         // Use cookie.txt for STORING cookies
    curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);        // Use cookie.txt for STORING cookies
    curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_POST, true);                 // Tell curl that we are posting data
    curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);          // Post the data in the array above
    $output = curl_exec($cr);
```